# Print a named vector in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have this named vector:

```
> foo = setNames(c("one", "two"), c(1, 2))
> foo
    1     2 
"one" "two" 
> names(foo)
[1] "1" "2"
> foo
    1     2 
"one" "two"
```

What is the easiest way to print the following:

```
1: one, 2: two
```

I just want it for debugging.

Could be with or without quotes, I'm not picky.

I've got this, but it seems very chatty:

```
the_vec = c()
for (idx in 1:length(foo)) {
  the_vec = c(the_vec, paste(idx, ":", foo[idx], sep=""))
}
paste(the_vec, collapse=", ")
```

output:

```
[1] "1:one, 2:two"
```

Comment: `cat()` might give you output that displays a little more to your liking.

Comment: @joel.wilson Nice! If you put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
paste(names(foo), foo, sep = ":", collapse = ",")
```

Comment: would the person who downvoted help me improve the bad answer I wrote?

Comment: use `writeLines` if using tabs or newlines to have them display